# Is it possible to build from one Mac and launch the Simulator on another?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I've got two Macs and when doing iPad dev, it interests me if it's possible to have another Mac launch the Simulator and load the app after a build is completed.

Would be nice to have an iPad app running in the Simulator on one Mac's screen and Xcode and all the editing being done in another.

I don't expect that this is even remotely possible, or worthwhile, but simply understanding why it would or wouldn't be possible would be worthwhile.

Comment: Please explain the reason. Maybe there is another solution. Maybe you just need a second screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed that is possible!

You can simply transfer your app to `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications` directory, reload the simulator, and it will magically appear as installed!

Or I believe, you can just run your app using a tool like [`ios-sim`](https://github.com/phonegap/ios-sim) without copying it to simulator folder.

Comment: Hmmmm.  So, derived data is not required.  Interesting.  That's awesome.  This is a GREAT way to distribute it to multiple machines for testing if I set the target folder up to be watched.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I really don't think this is possible. I know that Xcode 5 has some CI action going on but I don't think you can target the iOS simulator with it. I know it can run unit tests on attached devices (not the simulator, an actual device) and it can archive your applications for distribution. Not sure about running it on a separate machine.

You can always copy your code to your second mac and run Xcode from it to run the app in the simulator, that's pretty much the only way I can think of.

Comment: Yeah, I can commit to a repo and then update from the repo on the other mac and run, but that's inviting me to start editing on the wrong Mac.  Thanks anyway.